# Responsive site -> Galaxy S3 -> Radio Buttons Showing Intermittently

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-2, samsung-mobile

I am working on a responsive site, utilising bootstrap and MVC2.

Out UAT testers have noticed a strange issue occurring only on Samsung Galaxy S3 devices. I have attached three screenshots of the issue, but it looks like the S3 is randomly displaying the native radio button controls where we have styled the radio button control.

The dev team and testers have been trying to reliably re-create this issue, but we have only seen it happen 3-4 times over the past 2 months, lots of testing is taking place..

Has anyone seen this behaviour before the the S3, and any ideas how we might prevent it from ever happening? We aren't overly concerned about it, but would be nice to understand whats happening.[image: Sample]

[image: Sample2]